# recaptcha when using BeautifulSoup in colab but not locally

Tags: python, web-scraping, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I've written a script to scrape data from a div and return a boolean if a prespecified string exists within the div class, everything works perfectly locally. However, when I copy the code to a colab notebook the script hits the ReCaptcha and returns a 403 status code.

My code is below:

```
def stock_checker(listofurls):

       headers = {
       'User-Agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like 
        Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.88 Safari/537.36"
        }

       stock_level = []

       for target_url in tqdm(listofurls): 
           print(target_url)
           query = requests.get(target_url,headers=headers).text
           html = soup(query, "html.parser")
           soup_result = html.find("div", {"class": "product-details__options-basket"}).text
           stock_bool = "Out of Stock" if "Out of Stock" in str(soup_result) else "In Stock"
           stock_level.append(stock_bool)

        return pd.DataFrame({"URls" : listofurls, "In Stock" : stock_level})

print(stock_checker(myurllist))
```

The html returned is for the ReCaptcha and therefore the div I'm referencing further down does not exist and the code errors.

Any ideas on why this is happening in colab and not locally? and/or how to fix the issue?

Ps - I'm putting it in colab so others can use by just running the code without needing to code.

Answer (score 0):

RE: "why is this happening?" --

Headless browsers are often used for abuse, and hence more often receive counter-abuse tests like captchas. The chance is likely greater when executing from shared IP ranges typical of Cloud providers.

The short version is that the site you are using is probably working as intended. If you are not adhering to its `robots.txt` directives, I'd start there in order to reduce the chance of encountering counter-abuse mechanisms.